# On the definition of Cauchy transform

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, measure-theory, potential-theory, several-complex-variables

I have seen two different definitions of the Cauchy transform of a smooth function one is with respect to  the line integral (for eg. in. the book *"The Cauchy transform and potential theory"*) and another is with respect to complex differential (for eg. in PDE of SCV by M.-C. Shaw and S.-C. Chen). How these two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: I guess this can only happen if the integration of smooth function with respect to line integral is finite iff the integration  of smooth function with respect to complex differential is finite.

Comment: you might want to make this question self-contained by writing down the two formulas you mention; in particular the second formula ("in PDE of SCV") is not easily located.